# Selection criteria live in master page or content page?

Tags: asp.net, architecture, user-interface, master-pages

Scenario:

1. Four or so dropdowns with labels that the user can change.
2. After user changes the dropdowns a grid below will change
3. Several pages will reuse this design, but the grid may have different columns and there may be other grids that get added.

Question:  Where to place these selections?
The two obvious choices are:

1. Place the selection criteria directly on the master page and access the values in the content page or
2. Place the selection criteria in a user control that lives on each of the content pages.

Pros/Cons for #1:

1. Pro - More maintainable because they live on a single master page instead of on each content page
2. Con - Requires content pages to subscribe to change events

Pros/Cons for #2

1. Pro - Don't have to subscribe to change events
2. Con - less maintainable, because each content page has to figure out what to do with the selections.

Can anyone make an argument why one is better than the other?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"***Content pages to subscribe to change events***" doesn't seem to be either a benefit or a drawback without further elaboration. You cannot really morph it to either category by prefixing "Do" or "Don't".

The logic above (if you agree) leaves us with the following choices:

#### 1

- Pros - More maintainable because they live on a single master page
  instead of on each content page
- Cons - None

#### 2

- Pros - None
- Cons - less maintainable, because each content page has to figure out what to do with the selections.

The choice is rather clear if you don't want to throw in more criteria.

Comment: I agree, but I was hoping for someone else to give some pro/cons besides the ones I mentioned or to expand on them.